# SQL. Join with filter and offset

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a SQL query that will return images with tags. The result should be ordered by some column and filtered by UserID and tags. The result should be paginated.

There is a SQL statement

```
SELECT img.*, t.Name
FROM Image img
INNER JOIN ImageTag it on it.ImageID = img.ImageID
INNER JOIN Tag t on t.TagID = it.TagID
WHERE img.UserID = 1 and t.Name in ('first','second')
ORDER BY img.CreatedAt OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

This request is not working as expected. I expect to get 50 images, but they will be combined with tags and the result will be something like ...

```
| Image.ImageID | Tag.Name | ... |
| 1             | First    | ... |
| 1             | Second   | ... |
| 2             | First    | ... |
| 3             | First    | ... |
....
```

How do I get 50 images instead of 50 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `order by` to interleave the images:

```
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY img.ImageID ORDER BY NEWID()),
         img.CreatedAt
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

Basically, this enumerates the rows for each image, returning the "first" row.  Note:  If you don't have 50 images, then there will be duplicates as the code moves to the second tag.

If you want only one row per image with all tags, you can use `APPLY`:

```
SELECT img.*, t.tags
FROM Image img CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT STRING_AGG(t.Name, ',') as tags
      FROM ImageTag it JOIN
           Tag t 
           ON t.TagID = it.TagID
      WHERE it.ImageID = img.ImageID AND
            t.Name IN ('first', 'second')
     ) t
WHERE img.UserID = 1 
ORDER BY img.CreatedAt OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

This aggregates the tags for each image in the subquery, so only one row per image is returned.  This concatenates the tags together.  Of course, you could use other aggregation functions, such as `MIN()` or `MAX()`.

You can also use:

```
MIN(t.Name) + (CASE WHEN MIN(t.Name) <> MAX(t.Name) THEN ',' + MAX(t.Name) ELSE '' END)
```

Comment: The second query looks like what I'm looking for, but I don't have STRING_AGG function in SQL SERVER 2012. Also could you please explain why are you using CROSS APPLY, why not GROUP BY by all image columns?

Comment: @DmitryPolishuk . . . Because you are looking for just two values, you can use the `MIN()` and `MAX()`, which I added to the answer.  I use `CROSS APPLY` because I think it is the best way to express the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT img.*, t.Name
FROM Image img
INNER JOIN ImageTag it on it.ImageID = img.ImageID
INNER JOIN Tag t on t.TagID = it.TagID
INNER JOIN (SELECT ImageID FROM Image ORDER BY CreatedAt OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 
ROWS ONLY) img1 ON img1.ImageID=img.ImageID
WHERE img.UserID = 1 and t.Name in ('first','second')
```